# Unusual Traffic is being captured in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

When i go to site content -> all pages I am able to see that there is an usual traffic is being captured.

For example, there is an url like www.mycontent.com/articles. In Google analytics, i see it like "**www.mycontent.com/articles?{keyword}=**" which is not present in the website at all.

This is being captured as organic traffic. And it is affecting the data. Does anyone know from where that url is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

GA will capture parameters, anyone can add parameters to the url of your site. Could be bot traffic. I recommend you create another view on the same property and apply filters to improve the consistency of your data.